# Не запускается сервер node.js localhost: 8080

Tags: node.js

Здравствуйте, подскажите в чем проблема, не запускается сервер. Работало все хорошо. Но сейчас почему то выдает ошибку.  Как ее исправить? Пробовал переустановить node.js , не помогло
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Текст ошибки

```
Listening at http://localhost:8080

    (node:7720) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejec
    tion id: 1): Error: Exited with code 1
    (node:7720) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are depre
    cated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the
     Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: Текстом ошибку вставьте.

Comment: Текст ошибки вставил

Comment: `catch`  блок добавьте в цепочку вашего промиса https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2016/11/09/node-7-and-promise-rejections-please-handle-them/

Comment: Похожий вопрос https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40500490/what-is-an-unhandled-promise-rejection

Comment: Скорее всего у вас стоит восьмая версия ноды, а сервер написан под более раннюю.

Comment: @Beast Winterwolf стояла версия 8.2.1, я с ней работал нормально , ничего не менял, и сегодня появилась эта ошибка.

Comment: @SerhiyBilik ну значит не в ноде причина, а в сервере. Видимо автор решил, что промисы нужно отлавливать в обязательном порядке.  Suvitruf всё правильно сказал, добавьте обработчик `.catch(err)`.

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте обработчик [unhandledrejection](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_unhandledrejection) и посмотрите, что за ошибка.

```
process.on('unhandledRejection', (...args) => console.error(...args));
```

Comment: К сожалению не могу вставить код текстом.
Подскажите в чем дело?
Код ошибки http://prntscr.com/h9tyzy